# Microsoft word 2011 not correcting words in OS X

Tags: macos, ms-office, autocorrect

I am using Microsoft Word for Mac 2011.

Recently, I have noticed that the application is not highlighting my typos and spelling mistakes, neither autocorrecting it.

I have checked some online helps but nothing is helping at all.

Anyone using Word on Mac facing the same issue? 
Any resolution?

OS: Yosemite 
Office 2011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my question is here:

Go to **Tools** > **Language...** > Select your preferred language. For me it was **English(US)**

[image]